# Dataproc: dependency on cluster's HDFS when submitting Spark job to YARN from an edge node

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a running Dataproc cluster. I wanted to submit a Spark job directly to YARN with `spark-submit` from an **edge node outside of the cluster**. Ideally `spark-submit` should only need access to the YARN resource manager address, so we configured firewall rules to only allow that, but the job submission failed because it needed to access the cluster's HDFS.

Questions:

1. Why does `spark-submit` need to access HDFS?
2. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the property `spark.yarn.stagingDir` [1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties). The dir is used by `spark-submit` to stage jars and configs, so YARN can access and distribute them to executors. The default value is the current user's home directory in HDFS, but it can be set to a GCS dir to avoid HDFS, for example:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.yarn.stagingDir=gs://my-bucket/spark-staging/
```